# Outputting in a text box

Tags: php, sql, ajax, textbox, get

I'm currently using two pages, one is my Main.php and the other is just for PHP code (ajaxModule.php) to make my AJAX work. I am also using an SQL database which I made which I am using to retrieve data in order to populate select drop down lists and such. I have a text box which is where the user inputs the Module Code and the text box right below it, which is for the Module Name will automatically get filled out, so the user doesn't have to write it out. I am able to use the AJAX function below to retrieve the right Module Name but I can't get it to output into a text box, instead the only thing I've found that works is span. I realize a text box is just for input, but I have looked for ways to output in a text box but can't get them to work. I have also tried to pass the array of values I get from the PHP in the page with the AJAX in it back to the Main.php, in order to output it that way, but I can't seem to get that to work either.

Here is the code you need from my Main.php page:

```
<div id="slide3" class = "unactiveSlide">
<form id = "requestForm">
<div id = "requestdiv">
<table>

<tr><!-- This is where the user inputs the module code and the function is called with onkeyup-->
<td><a href="#" title="Enter the module code e.g. 'COB290' i.e. Department Code followed by Part and Actual Module Code">Module Code</a></td>
<?php
echo "<td>";
echo "<input type='text' size='40' id='moduleCodeID'  onkeyup='loadXMLDoc(this.value)'/>";
echo "</td>";
?>
</tr>

<tr><!-- This is where the module name appears with the use of AJAX-->
<td><a href="#" title="The name of the module e.g. 'Team Projects'">Module Name</a></td>                    
<?php
<td><span id='moduleCodeToNameDiv'></span></td>
</tr>

</table>
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

Here is the AJAX function which is above this code, also in the Main.php (q is the variable I've used in the next page to carry over the value):

```
<head>
<script>
//AJAX SCRIPT FOR MODULE CODE TO MODULE NAME

function loadXMLDoc(str)
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("moduleCodeToNameDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","ajaxModule.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
```

Here is the code in my AJAX file called ajaxModule.php:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php

$q = $_GET["q"];

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','team06');
if (!$con) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
mysqli_select_db($con,"reqs");

$sql = "SELECT Module_Title FROM module WHERE Module_Code = '" . $q."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))

{
echo $row['Module_Title'];
}
?>  
</body>
</html>
```

Could anyone please tell me how to get it output into a text box?
Thanks in advance,

Idris.

Answer (score 0):

To set an `<input>` value don't assign to `innerHTML` instead:

```
 Document.getElementById("xxx").value = xmlhttp.responseText;
```

Don't forget to escape `$q`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I just researched innerHTML but I don't quite understand where I'd put this code that you have given me. Could you please show me where I'd use it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well at the moment it tires to put it in `moduleCodeToNameDiv` ? Replace that ID with the input elements ID and swap `.innerHTML` for `.value`